# Getting current location in a Broadcast receiver- Android

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, locationmanager

My goal is to get a single pair of coordinates upon a received broadcast. What I've done so far is the following:

```
 @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // API 31 and above
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S){
            locationManager.getCurrentLocation(LocationManager.FUSED_PROVIDER, null, context.getMainExecutor(), new Consumer<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(Location location) {
                    if(location == null)
                        return;
                     
                    MyObject myObject = new MyObject(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                }
            });
        }

        // Legacy (API < 31)
        else{
            Criteria locationCriteria = new Criteria();
            locationCriteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
            locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(locationCriteria, new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(@NonNull Location location) {
                    MyObject myObject = new MyObject(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(@NonNull String provider) {
                    Log.d("SmsHandler", "PROVIDER ENABLED");
                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(@NonNull String provider) {
                    Log.d("SmsHandler", "PROVIDER DISABLED");
                }
            }, null);
        }
}
```

but it seems unstable. Should I use Services or something similar? Might I ask you why? I've read from the official documentation:

> If this BroadcastReceiver was launched through a  tag, then the object is no longer alive after returning from this function. This means you should not perform any operations that return a result to you asynchronously.

is that why? But to be honest I do not well understand what is being said very well (not so experienced with Android yet).

Furthermore, during some tests, if the user toggles the location just a second before the execution of the code above, neither `getCurrentLocation()` nor `onLocationChanged()` get fired, but, the next time the broadcast triggers `onReceive()`, `getCurrentLocation()` or `onLocationChanged()` get executed twice (like it remembers it did not execute the last time).

Might you be so kind to help me? Thank you.

Comment: start worker request that run background tack when onReceive is called in BroadCast reciver. put your location code in worker class.